# Using Pivot Component from Fabric React

Tags: sharepoint-online, fabric

I want to use the Pivot Component from Fabric React to create tabs so that I can put different SharePoint Lists into the each 'tab'.

Do I have to create a SharePoint Web part using the SharePoint Framework for this using the Fabric UI? Or can I achieve this just by referencing the Fabric React Components in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

`Pivot` Component is a part of `Fabric UI` framework. `Fabric UI` has realization in pure jS, `ReactJS` and `AngularJS`, so whenever you are using Fabric UI components you should use JS. 
For SharePoint's modern sites you should use SharePoint Framework (`SPFx`) only, no matter what realization are you choosing. But for regular sites you can use SP WebPart as well.